# How do you change the <title> element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, title

I have a HTML `<title>` element which I want to dynamically change depending on other elements. I tried using `document.getElementsByTagName('title').innerHTML = dynamicContent` but this did not seem to work. I have seen it done before, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean the `<title>` element in `<head>` of the page?
If yes, then changing `document.title` should do the trick.

Comment: How would you go about changing that Tom?  `document.title.innerHTML("New value");`?

Answer (score 7):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList, so you need to pick one element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = dynamicContent
```

There's also a shortcut to the title:

```
document.title = dynamicContent
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`, an array-like object but not an actual array.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate

a) document.title = 'blah';

b) .textContent or .innerText depending on the browser